# How to hide a button if the user is logged in using Elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm using Elementor to build a Wordpress website, I want to hide a button (Register) if the user is logged in.

I don't know how to test if the user session is opened or not to hide this button

Please help!

Comment: Screenshots? this makes it a lot easier for people to provide assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this plugin, it will do the trick:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/visibility-logic-elementor/

Edit Button > Show if all Conditions met and User Roll is Guest

[image: Show action - Conditions All - User Roll is Guest]

Comment: Time saving, thanks!

Comment: wonderful 

Thanks sir!